# Django: 'str' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, django, decorator

This is my code for the view:

```
@login_required
def get_top(type):
    o = Work.objects.filter(types = "Fan Fiction").order_by("-date_updated")[:10]
    list = []
    for o in o:
        l.title = o.title
        l.href = "/" + o.id
        list.append(l)
    return l

@login_required
def main_home(request):
    fanfiction = get_top("ff")
    poetry = get_top("pw")
    originalwork = get_top("ow")
    return render_to_response("Main/main_home.html", {'STATIC_URL':STATIC_URL, "poetry":poetry, "fan":fanfiction, "original":originalwork})
```

This is the code for the model:

```
class Work(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    summery = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date_published = models.DateField()
    date_updated = models.DateField()
    one_shot = models.BooleanField()
    completed = models.BooleanField()
    TYPES = (
        ('FF', 'Fan Fiction'),
        ('OF', 'Original Work'),
        ('PW', 'Poetry Work'),
        )
    types = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TYPES)
    fandom1 = models.ForeignKey(Book, blank = True, null= True, related_name='f_1')
    fandom2 = models.ForeignKey(Book, blank = True, null= True, related_name='f_2')
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title + '-' + self.user.email
```

This is the error: `'str' object has no attribute 'user'` at "get_top("ff")"

Answer (score 16):

Please remove `@login_required` decorator for `get_top` method.

What this is trying to do is, `@login_required` tries to verify if that user is logged in or not. this is trying to find a `User` object instance in `ff` which is a `str` hence the stacktrace. Normally `@login_required` gets `User` from `request` obj, but since you are not passing that in `get_top` hence the error.

My suggestion is you should maintain a certain set of methods in `views.py` which are linked to the API urls in `urls.py` some of these might require `@login_required`. other set of methods are helper method (like `get_top`). these are not exposed to outside world (hence no need for `@login_required`).

In case you must expose `get_top` both internally and externally, then your first parameter to `get_top` has to be `request` object then followed by other params.

Comment: Also would suggest to add that using `type` as a variable name is not recommended, because it is a python built in function.

Comment: hey @Mike, did my suggestion help you?

Comment: This helped me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

get_top does not return an HttpResponse, so Django cannot apply the @login_required decorator properly (it's assuming it gets back an HttpResponse which has a .user property)